# Updating an imageView all the time , Android

Tags: android, int

I´m doing a 2d render class(that renders an int array of pixels) and i want to show this pixels into the screen. I´ve tried with an ImageView but its not working; Is there any method like canvas on android ? Or How do you create an image that updates all the time ? (I have implemented the runnable class)

This is what I have done:

```
   @Override
public void run()
{
 Imageview exampleImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.exampleId);
 // This is a simple method to do the int array image;
 int[] img = new int[100]     
 for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
 img[i] = i*100;

  }
  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(10, 10, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

  bitmap.setPixels(img, 0, 10, 0, 0, 100, 100);
  exampleImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

Well, and it does not show anything on the screen

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should create a custom `View` and draw on `Canvas` which will fill the `Bitmap` underneath.

Override the [View#onDraw(Canvas)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) and draw the pixels with the [Canvas#drawPoints(float[], Paint)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPoints(float[],%20android.graphics.Paint)) method. Then you can use [View#postInvalidateDelayed(long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidateDelayed(long)) or some of it's sibling methods to force the `View` to redraw itself until your animation is finished.

You can find more info about Canvas and Drawables in [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) API Guide.